# Angular create empty model

Tags: angular, binding, model

***Editing because I don't think I explained this correctly given my lack of experience with Angular.

I have a component with a form that I use to update users (in this case as a child component) and I'd like to use the same component on another route by itself to create a new user but I can't seem to figure out how to use my user model on the "add a new user" instance. I get this error in my console when either screen loads:

```
TypeError: "_co.user is undefined"
```

I'm sure this means that my user model is not defined/initialized but I've tried and can't seem to figure it out. On the route where it's a being used as a child component to update users the forms works fine after I select a user, this populates the form and I can edit the information or delete the user. Here is a portion of my component.ts file and I was trying to create a new blank user model but that doesn't seem to be working either:

#### User Detail Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from  '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { User } from '../user';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

import { RouterModule, Router, Routes } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'app-user-detail',
templateUrl: './user-detail.component.html',
styleUrls: [ './user-detail.component.css' ]
})

export class UserDetailComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() user: User;

users: User[];

constructor(
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private userService: UserService,
private location: Location,
private router: Router
) {}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've been trying to resolve this for quite a while and can't figure out what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the place of initializing the user instance is wrong you define the user variable here `@Input() user: User;` and then redefine it `user = new User();`, I think this code leads to

> duplicate identifier error

Try this `@Input() user: User = new User();` instead and remove the second user definition
If you pass a user instance to UserDetailComponent correctly you can do this method and avoid having

> user not defined error

or any other error related to not defining the user variable

Comment: I updated my original post, I don't think I'm explaining this correctly, though I understand what you suggested somewhat.

Comment: @angler I read your question again please correct me if I am wrong you want to use the same component for an update and create a user with different routes?

Comment: Sort of, I wanted to use it as a child component for update/delete, and by itself on a separate route to add a new user.